# Cannot start training on Amazon SageMaker

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

```
def input_csv_fn():
    #filenames = np.load(file_io.FileIO(npy_file, 'r'))
    Dataset = tf.data.TextLineDataset(csv_file).skip(1).shuffle(buffer_size = 2000000).map(parser_csv, num_parallel_calls = cpu_count())
    #Dataset = Dataset.prefetch(2560)
    #Dataset = Dataset.shuffle(buffer_size = 1280)
    Dataset = Dataset.map(input_parser_plain, num_parallel_calls = cpu_count())
    Dataset = Dataset.apply(tf.contrib.data.ignore_errors())
    Dataset = Dataset.repeat(epochs)
    Dataset = Dataset.batch(batch_size)
    Dataset = Dataset.prefetch(batch_size)
    iterator = Dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
    feats, labs = iterator.get_next()
    return feats, labs
def aggregate_csv_batches():
    features = []
    labels = []
    # add if GPU exists condition here to fit GPU and CPU data processing
    if num_gpus > 0:
        num_devices = num_gpus
    else:
        num_devices = 1
    for i in range(num_devices):
        _features, _labels = input_csv_fn()
        features.append(_features)
        labels.append(_labels)
    return features, labels
return aggregate_csv_batches
```

Above is the code for reading the dataset from S3 bucket via CSV, but when I am trying to do that I while I am creating the training job on AWS Sagemaker I am getting the following error constantly

> TypeError: Failed to convert object of type `<type 'function'>` to
>   Tensor. Contents: function aggregate_csv_batches at 0x7f1559eeaaa0.
>   Consider casting elements to a supported type.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to determine the problem without more details. Are you running this code using the SageMaker Tensorflow image in a training job? If so, have you read the docs here? https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/blob/master/src/sagemaker/tensorflow/README.rst

From just the error message, it looks like you're passing the function itself (aggregate_csv_batches) somewhere that expects a tensor.

If you can provide the complete code you're running and a description of how you're running it, or even better a minimal repro case, I can try to help further.